# Get params Angular

Tags: angular, routeparams

I have problem with params. I am using filter method to get every key, value from different componet (form).

The problem is with result in the end.

```
 filterTable(filters: { data: any; isReset: boolean }) {
    let params = new HttpParams();

    for (const key in filters.data) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(filters.data, key)) {
        const jsonData = JSON.stringify({ drilldown: { [key]: { op: 'EQ', value: filters.data[key] } } });
        params = params.append('filter', jsonData);
      }
    }
```

[image]

Is there way how could i not add in query params key with null value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the entire filter, just add this condition to your if :   **filters.data[key]**

```js
for (const key in filters.data) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(filters.data, key) && filters.data[key]) {
        const jsonData = JSON.stringify({ drilldown: { [key]: { op: 'EQ', value: filters.data[key] } } });
        params = params.append('filter', jsonData);
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to remove every value wich is null. So in parrams would be only for example 
filter: {"drilldown": {"L_BRAND":{"op":"EQ", "value": "test"}}}

Comment: Sorry. But now i try it and thats exactly what i need. Going to mark this as resolve. Ty

Comment: is it better to use `filters.data[key] !== null`? because if the value is 0, it will not be set as well